# Can I express $x^7y+xy+x+1$ by a repeated use of operation $xy+x+y+1$?

Tags: functions, puzzle, computational-mathematics

A certain calculator can only give the result of $xy+x+y+1$ for any two real numbers $x$ and $y$.

How to use this calculator to calculate $x^7y+xy+x+1$ for any given $x$ and $y$?

When $x$ and $y$ are equal, it will give $(x+1)^2$. But I cannot proceed beyond that.

Comment: May I ask you the origin of this question on computability ?

Answer (score 0):

Give $x^7$ and $y$ to the calculator, to get $R_1 = x^7y + x^7+y +1$.
Give $x$ and $y$ to the calculator, to get $R_2 = xy+x+y+1$.
Add $R_1$ and $R_2$ to get, $R = R_1+R_2 = x^7y + x^7 + x+xy + 2y+1$.
Subtract $x^7$ and $2y$ from $R$ to get the required.

Comment: I found this question a little confusing since it does not say anything about whether we can do some elementary calculation, such as addition and multiplication, as we've done in this answer. If not, it seems impossible fo finish; if we can, then why bother using that calculator? $x^7y+xy+x+1$ can be calculated directly.

Comment: @CaveJohnson I'm assuming you can do addition and subtraction of value you have and that's about it. It is a bit of an illformed question though.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Give $(x,x)$ to the calculator to get $x^2 + 2x + 1$ and subtract $2x + 1$ from this. You can even get $2x$ from the calculator by giving in $(x,1)$ to get $2x + 2$.
2. Now, using prev result, give $(x^2, x^2)$ to get $x^4+ 2x^2 + 1$. Use previous result to obtain $x^4$.
3. Using previous result, give $(x^4, x^2)$ to get $x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + 1$. Subtract values to get $x^6$.
4. Give $(x^6, x)$ to get $x^7 + x^6 + x + 1$ and from this extract $x^7$.
5. Give $(x^7, y)$ to get $x^7y + x^7 + y + 1$. From this pull out the $x^7y$ to get $x^7y$
6. Give $(x,y)$ to get $xy + x + y + 1$. From this pull out the $y$ to get $xy + x + 1$
7. Add 5. and 6. to get $x^7y + xy + x + 1$.

This question makes little sense. Are there more stringent rules on what you aren't allowed to do?